# Formatting WebView Font & Size

Tags: xcode

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body bgcolor=#0058AA text=#FFFFFF font-family: Futura>%@</body>",[item objectForKey:@"summary"]];
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

I'm using the code above to display text from an RSS feed. The only thing that doesn't work is the font-family...anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9321-setting-uiwebview-font.html Hope this helps.